# Copy data from one spreadsheet to another

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I am trying to copy data from one spreadsheet to another (which will already have data in). I need to copy (from source spreadsheet) all populated cells to column B in the destination spreadsheet but at the last row (not overwriting existing data)

here is what I have so far but it is not exactly what I need and is throwing an error saying:

> object required

at this line: `Last_Row = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)`

And I'm trying to do this in a **.VBS file**

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True

Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("D:\Test2.xlsx")
Set objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet 2")

Set objRange = objWorksheet.Range("A5:D5")
objRange.Copy

'destination spreadsheet stuff:
Set objExcel2 = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel2.Visible = True
Set objWorkbook2 = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("D:\Test1.xlsx")
Set objWorksheet2 = objWorkbook2.Worksheets("Sheet1")   

Last_Row = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
objWorksheet2.Range("B" & Last_Row).Activate
objWorksheet2.Paste
```

Comment: that is not VB.NET code

Comment: that was a suggested tag I will remove it.

Comment: if its not VBscript code then what is it?

Comment: VBA = Visual Basic for Applications. It is a hosted language available primarily in MS Office applications.

Comment: From where are you running this code?  You're creating TWO new instances of Excel application. This is almost certainly not optimal.

Comment: from my laptop. this might not be the best way of doing this or even the best language. I am not a programmer so need any help possible :)

Comment: Your code does not do want you want at all. If you want it to copy all data from a spreadsheet you should be using UsedRange to return the range that has data. You definitely cannot just set a range as A5:D5

Comment: @ClintStreet Yes, you can absolutely set a range as A5:D5. Did you try it?

Comment: "from my laptop" -- what does this mean? How are you executing this code?

Comment: @DavidZemens I know you can but the op says this " I need to copy (from source spreadsheet) all populated cells to column B". I am hinting that the UsedRange would work best to get all populated cells.

Comment: While that may be an issue for OP eventually, at least for the time being, *that* does not appear to be the problem as indicated in OP, which is a very specific error on a specific line.  @ClintStreet

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba

Comment: If you qualify the Range with objWorksheet2 as `Last_Row = objWorksheet2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` then you should not get the error.

Comment: I am trying to run it from a .vbs file

Answer (score 1):

I changed `Last_Row` to `Next_Row` because, you'll want to paste on the next line after the data (hence `+ 1`).

And got rid of the second Excel instance, because pasting between two instances is very limited and programmatically very inefficient!

So this should work just fine :

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True

Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("D:\Test2.xlsx")
Set objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet 2")

Set objRange = objWorksheet.Range("A5:D5")
objRange.Copy

'destination spreadsheet stuff:
Set objWorkbook2 = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("D:\Test1.xlsx")
Set objWorksheet2 = objWorkbook2.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Next_Row = objWorksheet2.Range("B" & objWorksheet2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
objWorksheet2.Range("B" & Next_Row).Paste
```

Comment: I get an unknown error from this. I should probably have explained I am trying to execute it from a .vbs file.

Comment: Indeed it would have been good to know! Not sure how to do this in VBS though... :/